# Py2app not functioning as desired to create an app for mac

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm very new to working on MacOS, but I need to make an app that Mac users can utilize. It's supposed to be a simple plug-and-play app, that is to say that I want to make sure that all they need to do is download the Mac executable file and then they can use the app freely. My app currently seems to be working perfectly fine, that is at least while I'm running the program using the PyCharm IDE, which is also where I compiled my code. This app works through the IDE on the original machine, as well as any other device that I can install the IDE and the other required packages (wand). However, when creating an app through py2app and running it, I get the following error:

> avery@averys-MacBook-Air-2 Patents %
> ./dist/PatDrawDemo.app/Contents/MacOS/PatDrawDemo
>
> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py",
> line 1892, in **call**
>
> ```
> return self.func(*args)
> ```
>
> File "/Users/avery/Documents/Patents/PatDrawDemo.py", line
> 165, in get_input
>
> ```
> fig_one(txt, int(ct))
> ```
>
> File "/Users/avery/Documents/Patents/PatDrawDemo.py", line
> 105, in fig_one
>
> ```
> fig1.save(filename='PatDrawFig1.png')
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wand/image.py",
> line 9892, in save
>
> ```
> self.raise_exception()
> ```
>
> File
> "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wand/resource.py",
> line 222, in raise_exception
>
> ```
> raise e
> ```
>
> wand.exceptions.CoderError: WriteBlob Failed `PatDrawFig1.png' @
> error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1713

I imagine that the error I'm getting is due to the path to which it's supposed to save to is invalid or unreachable or something of the sort, but then again I honestly don't know what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there's anything that is needed in addition to what I've posted, please let me know. Below is just a snippet of the code where 'PatDrawFig1.png' is saving.

```
def fig_one(full_text, ct):
    target_width = 375
    y_offset = 0
    y_padding = 5
    x_padding = 7

    with Image(width=2000, height=5000, pseudo='xc:white') as fig1:
        for match in find_matches(text=full_text):
            with Drawing() as ctx:
                ctx.font_size = 20
                ctx.text_alignment = 'center'
                words = match.split(" ")
                word_count = len(words)
                while True:
                    temp_text = rebuild_text(words, word_count, str(ct))
                    metrics = ctx.get_font_metrics(fig1, temp_text, multiline=True)
                    if metrics.text_width > target_width:
                        word_count -= 1
                    else:
                        text = temp_text
                        target_height = int(metrics.text_height + 1)
                        break
                ctx.push()
                ctx.fill_color = 'white'
                ctx.stroke_width = 3
                ctx.stroke_color = 'black'
                ctx.rectangle(2, y_offset + y_padding, width=2*x_padding+target_width,
                              height=2*y_padding+target_height)
                ctx.pop()
                ctx.text(x_padding+3 + (target_width // 2), 10 + 4*y_padding+y_offset, text)
                ctx(fig1)
                y_offset += target_height + 4*y_padding - 2
            ct += 2
        fig1.trim()
        fig1.save(filename='PatDrawFig1.png')
        open_image('PatDrawFig1.png')
        exit()
```

Also let me know if there's any other sort of clarification needed.